# Ansible adding items to nested list

Tags: ansible, nested, fact

starting data:

```
ok: [test@test.com] => {
    "msg": {
        "testdb1": {
            "dbe_user_not_in_db": [
                "test_user1", 
                "test_user2"
            ], 
        }
    }
}
```

I currently have the following in ansible:

```
    - name: Create dbe_pass_pairs
      set_fact:
        ora_sid_home_map: "{{ora_sid_home_map|combine({ item[0].key: {'dbe_pass_pairs': {item[1]: password} }}, recursive=True)}}"
      loop: "{{ ora_sid_home_map | dict2items | subelements('value.dbe_user_not_in_db') }}"
      vars:
        password: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=10 chars=ascii_letters,digits') }}"
```

Which yields:

```
ok: [test@test.com] => {
    "msg": {
        "testdb1": {
            "dbe_pass_pairs": {
                "test_user1": "4SS2kJ7p0z", 
                "test_user2": "VLIzNfoaxf"
            }, 
            "dbe_user_not_in_db": [
                "test_user1", 
                "test_user2"
            ], 
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of dbe_pass_pairs containing dictionary items I'd like them to be a list of strings like such with a semicolon as:

```
ok: [test@test.com] => {
    "msg": {
        "testdb1": {
            "dbe_pass_pairs": [
                "test_user1;4SS2kJ7p0z", 
                "test_user2;VLIzNfoaxf"
            ], 
            "dbe_user_not_in_db": [
                "test_user1", 
                "test_user2"
            ], 
        }
    }
}
```

Doing something like the following just overwrite the list instead of appending:

```
    - name: Create dbe_pass_pairs
      set_fact:
        ora_sid_home_map: "{{ora_sid_home_map|combine({ item[0].key: {'dbe_pass_pairs': [item[1] + ';' + password] }}, recursive=True)}}"
      loop: "{{ ora_sid_home_map | dict2items | subelements('value.dbe_user_not_in_db') }}"
      vars:
        password: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=10 chars=ascii_letters,digits') }}"
```

```
            "dbe_pass_pairs": [
                "test_user2;AxL6ayeZIH"
            ],
```

Any idea how to get what I'm looking for data wise?

Comment: you show the result waited, but could you show your starting data?

Comment: Certainly! I added starting data to original post

Answer (score 0):

a solution using jinja2:

```
- name: Reproduce issue
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  vars:
    ora_sid_home_map:
      testdb1:
        dbe_user_not_in_db: ["test_user1", "test_user2"]
  tasks:      
    - name: Create paswords
      set_fact:
        ora_sid_home_map: >-
              {%- set ns=namespace(result=[], ident="", final={}) -%}
              {%- set ns.ident = ora_sid_home_map |first -%}              
              {%- for user in ora_sid_home_map[ns.ident].dbe_user_not_in_db -%}
              {%- set password = lookup('password', '/dev/null length=10 chars=ascii_letters,digits') -%}            
              {%- if ns.result.append(user ~ ';' ~ password) -%}{%- endif -%}
              {%- endfor -%}
              {{ {ns.ident: ora_sid_home_map[ns.ident] | combine({'dbe_pass_pairs': ns.result})} }}
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ora_sid_home_map }}"
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "testdb1": {
            "dbe_pass_pairs": [
                "test_user1;tPOSfCzLLq",
                "test_user2;e0A92Dkuac"
            ],
            "dbe_user_not_in_db": [
                "test_user1",
                "test_user2"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

without jinja2:

```
- name: Reproduce issue
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  vars:
    ora_sid_home_map:
      testdb1:
        dbe_user_not_in_db: ["test_user1", "test_user2"]
  tasks:      
    - name: Create paswords
      set_fact:
        passwords: "{{ passwords | d([]) + [data] }}"
      loop: "{{ ora_sid_home_map[ident].dbe_user_not_in_db }}"
      vars:
        password: "{{ lookup('password', '/dev/null length=10 chars=ascii_letters,digits') }}"
        data: "{{ item ~ ';' ~ password }}"
        ident: "{{ ora_sid_home_map|first }}"
    - name: result
      set_fact:
        ora_sid_home_map: "{{ {ident: data} }}"
      vars:
        ident: "{{ ora_sid_home_map|first }}"
        data: "{{ ora_sid_home_map[ident]| combine({'dbe_pass_pairs': passwords}) }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ora_sid_home_map }}"
```

Comment: Thank you Frenchy! This is great. How would think look if say the value testd1 was dynamic. This playbook will get ran across many servers and that value will change.

Comment: see my answer modified in this case the first key is dynamic and set in variable ident

Comment: @user2763181 dont forget to close your question by validating and updating the answer..thanks